# Redirector outside of Zend controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have a class in my library folder (My_Class) - it's not a controller. I have TRY-CATCH block in it and I want to immediately redirect from CATCH block. It is possible to do it this way?

```
    My_Class{

        public function MyFunction(){

            $this->MyOtherFunction();
            //do more stuff

       }

        private function MyOtherFunciton(){

          try{

          //throw exception

          } catch (Exception $e) {

                $redirector = new Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector();
                $redirector->gotoSimpleAndExit('action','controller','default');
            }


        }
```

It redirects, but does it redirect immediately? Or can "//do more stuff" be processed?
Thank you

PS: Class is called from controller:

```
    //in controller
    $myclass = new My_Class();
    $myclass->MyFunction();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it does redirect immediately. You can check it out yourself in the file 
/Zend/Controller/Action/Helper/Redirector.php

There is also a gotoSimple() function that maybe does not redirect right away.

Answer (score 0):

```
setExit() can be used to force an exit() following a redirect. By default this is TRUE.
```

you could try `$redirector->setExit(false)->setGotoSimple()`, I've never had a reason to do anything after a redirect so I haven't tried this feature out.